# How does Button Click fire httphandler Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, httphandler

I have a webform application.

The page has a from which contains a set of textboxes and one **ASP:FileUploader**.

A button called **"Upload"** will uploaded the file separately from saving the whole form.

I set up a httpHandler to upload files in chunks, and it should be fired after user click "Upload".

They only way I worked out is set the `PostBackURL` attribute in the "Upload" button. e.g.

> PostBackURL = ".upload"

which maps to the httpHandler's Path.

But my problem is "PostBackURL" is a Redirect , It does fire the httpHandler but it will direct to ".upload" page (which its content is empty ) , and user lost information in other textboxes.

So what is the best way to fire a httpHandler and let the browser stay in the current page? Is iframe the only option?

Comment: Either have the button post the form to a hidden iframe, or else set something up with HTML5 file APIs (which won't work for IE).

Comment: @Pointy I use JavaScript to let the from post to a hidden iframe, (add target=my_iframe), but after I uploading the file in httphandler, how do I reset the from to submit on itself and reload the page and keep information in textboxes unchanged? Why not write an answer? :)

Comment: I didn't have enough information before to know what sort of answer to write, but what you just wrote in the comment is enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

To post to a hidden `<iframe>` element, the general pattern that I've always followed is:

1. Set the target of the form to point to the name of the `<iframe>` element. (Generally I give the `<iframe>` the same "name" and "id" value out of old habit; it may not be necessary.)
2. Post the form. That'll initiate the HTTP transaction but it won't blow away the page that the form is on.
3. The *response* to the POST should be a page with nothing on it (or almost nothing) except some JavaScript. That code can talk to the parent page to tell it either that there was a problem with the file upload (like, you wanted an image file, and the file posted was text) or that the upload succeeded. In either case, the parent page can update itself with either an error message or some success message.
4. At that point, the form "target" attribute can be cleared.

When the `<form>` is to be posted "normally", you might want to disable the file `<input>`. (Depends on your situation.